# Linked Stack template and a bunch of errors

Tags: c++, stack

Would anyone tell me what I did wrong ? If I comment out all the statements inside the main function, the compiler is not going to complain. So, I think it has something to do with the main function, right when I create a new instance of LinkedStack.

**LinkedNode.h**

```
#include<memory>

template<class T>
class LinkedNode
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedNode<T>& obj);

    public:
        LinkedNode(T newElement);
        T GetElement() const {return element;}
        void SetElement(T val) {element = val;}
        LinkedNode<T>* GetNext() const {return next;}
        void SetNext(LinkedNode<T>* val) {next = val;}
    private:
        T element;
        LinkedNode<T>* next;
};


template<class T>
LinkedNode<T>::LinkedNode(T newElement)
{
    element = newElement;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedNode<T>& obj)
{
    os << obj.element << endl;
    return os;
}
```

**LinkedStack.h**

```
#pragma once
#include"LinkedNode.h"
#include<cassert>

template<class T>
class LinkedStack
{
    public:
        LinkedStack();
        int GetSize() const {return size;}
        bool IsEmpty() const {return size == 0;}
        void Push(T val);
        void Pop();
        T Peek();
        void Clear();
    private:
        LinkedNode<T>* head;
        int size;

};


template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack():size(0) {}

template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::Push(T val)
{
    LinkedNode<T>* newOne = new LinkedNode<T>(val);
    if(head == 0)
        head = newOne;
    else
    {
        newOne->next = head;
        head = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::Pop()
{
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    LinkedNode<T>* tpHead = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tpHead;
    size--;
}

template<class T>
T LinkedStack<T>::Peek()
{
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    return head->element;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::Clear()
{
    while(!IsEmpty())
        Pop();
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include"LinkedStack.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>

int main()
{
    LinkedStack<int> stack;

    std::cout << "Add" << std::endl;
    stack.Push(1);
    stack.Push(2);
    stack.Push(3);
    stack.Push(4);
    stack.Push(5);
    std::cout << "Top element is: " << stack.Peek();
    stack.Pop();
    std::cout << "After pop one out, its top element is: " << stack.Peek() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is all the errors that I've got:

```
    Warning 29  warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of '_Collvec' when no variable is declared  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xlocinfo.h   58
Error   4   error C3857: 'LinkedStack': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    5
Error   3   error C2989: 'LinkedStack' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    20
Error   26  error C2989: 'lconv' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\locale.h 82
Error   27  error C2989: 'lconv' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\locale.h 109
Error   5   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    23
Error   12  error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    40
Error   21  error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   9   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    27
Error   17  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    51
Error   25  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring  13
Error   2   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkednode.h 6
Error   11  error C2182: 'LinkedStack' : illegal use of type 'void' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    40
Error   19  error C2182: 'LinkedStack' : illegal use of type 'void' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   28  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'identifier' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xlocinfo.h   58
Error   10  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    40
Error   18  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    27
Error   16  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    51
Error   24  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring  13
Error   20  error C2086: 'int LinkedStack' : redefinition   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '<' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkednode.h 6
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : '<' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    23
Error   13  error C2059: syntax error : '<' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    40
Error   22  error C2059: syntax error : '<' e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   7   error C2039: 'Push' : is not a member of '`global namespace''   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    26
Error   14  error C2039: 'Pop' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    40
Error   15  error C2039: 'Peek' : is not a member of '`global namespace''   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    50
Error   23  error C2039: 'Clear' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    57
Error   30  error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xlocinfo.h(18)' was matched c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xlocinfo.h   58
```

Comment: I took your code, I made one change only, I commented out `private:` in LinkedNode.h and then it compiled for me. I can see no reason why the code posted would give the errors posted. The only suggestion I can make is to add an include guard to LinkedNode.h. But I think there's something going on here that hasn't been posted.

Comment: The only problem that i see in my compiler was private: in LinkedNode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked Stack and its template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268188/linked-stack-and-its-template-class)

Comment: Maybe the best suggestion is to start again. I see from the previous question that you've hacked this code around quite a bit. Clearly something has gone wrong when you did that. The code here isn't perfect, but there's nothing here that should cause the errors you are seeing. So start from scratch, use the code you posted above and nothing else. And see how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your header files.  The reason you don't see a compiler error when you comment out your `main` function is due to how templates work (they are basically a foundation to create an object, but the definition isn't actually created until you attempt to instantiate one).

It looks like you are missing a header guard in your LinkedNode.h file.  Place a `#pragma once` at the top of it (or use #ifndef/#define).  But I don't think that is the cause of your errors.

It appears you have declared a non-template version of `LinkedStack`, or potentially have the following syntax somewhere (that you haven't shown):

```
template<class T>
template<class N>
class LinkedStack {... }
```

For template classes this small, I'd recommend writing them inline as it will usually make your error easier to notice.